# Rails Include Admin access in before action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I wonder if anyone can help. I have below my current setup for an app where only an admin user should be able to see the user index: This works fine. Also non admin users are  redirected to root This also works fine (although I would like to redirect them to their user profile)

The real problem is that I would like admin users to be able to visit the user profile page of any user from the index page link, but at the moment he can only visit his own page. I see that this is because the correct_user before action lists `:show`

I have tried adding a :show action to the ':admin_user before action',  but it doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
    before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
    before_action :admin_user, only: [:index]
```

define correct_user

```
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
end
```

define admin_user

```
 def admin_user
  if current_user.admin?
   flash.now[:success] = "Admin Access Granted"
  else
   redirect_to root_path
  end
 end
```

SESSIONS- sessions_helper.rb

define current_user

```
  def current_user?(user)
   user == current_user
  end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done! Just add this to `correct_user`

```
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin?
end
```

Your code currently redirects to root unless the current user is the one requesting the user resource, just extend the `unless` statement with `User#admin?`

Furthermore, to redirect to the user's own profile, change the `correct_user`'s redirect statement to become this:

```
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to user_path(@user) unless current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin?
end
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that your admins are `User` objects that respond to `User#admin?`, updated my answer

Comment: Thanks replying so quickly let me give it a whirl, it makes perfect sense, but lets see if it identifies any conflicts or issues with the rest of my code. fingers crossed.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest thing to do would be put in a logical exception if the user is an admin. I've all taken an educated guess at your routes and redirected to the current users profile page instead of root.

```
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(user_path(current_user)) unless (current_user?(@user) && current_user.admin?)
end
```

Comment: Because you're using an `unless` statement, you don't need the bang (!) before the `current_user.admin?` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I switched it to an if statement and the mistake was clear.